# What type of datastructure does 'collections.defaultdict(set)' create?

Tags: python, set, defaultdict, conceptual, language-concepts

Here, we are using set as the missing value default, how can we use an undefined set for that purpose?

Comment: What do you mean by "undefined"?

Comment: What is provided the defaultdict constructor is a *factory*, a no-argument callable that -- when called -- produces new independent default values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`defaultdict` doesn't take a *value*, it takes a callable thing that it can *call* (with no arguments) to construct the value when it needs to. Typically a constructor of a class, or a function, like `lambda: 'Hello'`.

Each new value will in this case be a `set()`, which is an empty set.

```py
>>> d = collections.defaultdict(set)
>>> print(d['new_key'])
set()
```

Your datastructure is a dictionary of keys to sets, with an empty set as the default value.

Comment: Well, doesn't have to be constructor. Any no-arg callable will do.

Comment: Good point. Quite common to have a lambda in there so i updated the text.

Comment: Also, `set` *has* a constructor (`__new__`, though you probably meant `__init__`); it *is* a type.